# Nginx url rewrite WordPress and ModPageSpeed conflict

Tags: wordpress, nginx, plesk, mod-pagespeed

I'm using Plesk with nginx + ModPagespeed + WordPress

To lazy load images there is a placeholder image which should be loaded form this kind of URL
https://example.com/pagespeed_static/1.JiBnMqyl6S.gif it's dynamic, there is not actual folder so WordPress tries to send it to index.php, because of this WordPress rule set in nginx:

`if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; }`

Which is the correct approach to allow it to load image? Should I check if the URL is equal to that request and then inside adding the WordPress rule?

```
if($url != 'pagespeed_static/1.JiBnMqyl6S.gif') {
   if (!-e $request_filename) { 
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
   }
}
```

Ps. Just noticed that there is the same problem with .js which is caught by WordPress related rule, the URL is https://example.com/pagespeed_static/js_defer.I4cHjq6EEP.js

Here the contents of nginx directives file:

```
# PAGESPEED - - - - - - - - - - 

pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }

pagespeed CriticalImagesBeaconEnabled true;

pagespeed PreserveUrlRelativity on;
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization off;
pagespeed EnableFilters add_head;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_heads;
pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_import_to_link;
pagespeed EnableFilters outline_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters outline_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments;
pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_google_fonts_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_style_attribute;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_style_attributes_with_url;
pagespeed EnableFilters flatten_css_imports;
pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
pagespeed EnableFilters sprite_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters defer_javascript;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_to_webp_lossless;
pagespeed EnableFilters insert_image_dimensions;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters jpeg_subsampling;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_jpeg;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_png;
pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_webp;
pagespeed EnableFilters lazyload_images;
pagespeed LazyloadImagesAfterOnload off;
pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_color_profile;
pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_meta_data;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_rendered_image_dimensions;
pagespeed EnableFilters inline_preview_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters resize_mobile_images;
pagespeed DisableFilters elide_attributes;
pagespeed DisableFilters include_js_source_maps;
pagespeed EnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch;

# WORDPRESS - - - - - - - - - - - - -

location ~ /\.ht { deny all; }
location ~* wp-config.php { deny all; }
location ~* "^/wp-content/(?!plugins/).*\.php" { deny all; }
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using another solution proposed on some plesk support page.
So instead of using

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; }
```

whe should use

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { set $test P; }
if ($uri !~ ^/(pagespeed|plesk-stat|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat|awstats-icon)) { set $test "${test}C"; }
if ($test = PC) { rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1; }
```

Comment: Yet would like to see some better alternative without using "if"s

Answer (score 0):

I have never used plesk, but normally I would just replace those `if` lines with `try_files`, like so:

```
try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

This sends all requests to existing files to those files and all other requests to `index.php` with the requested URL and possible other arguments as argument, like in your code.

As you only showed part of the config I can't judge whether the `try_files` line needs to be outside the `location` blocks or inside one.

As a general guideline, following the [nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), I try to avoid `if` wherever possible (sometimes, admittedly, it isn't possible).